# How do I get rid of a corrupt table and FK in firebird

Tags: firebird, firebird-4.0

I tried to drop a table (tableA) that has a foreign to another table (tableB). Something went wrong during the process and now when I try to backup the db I get the internal consistency check error in the screenshot:[firebird error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCKeC.png).

I have tried gfix -mend -ig and even Ibsurgeon's firstAid software.

I don't need to recover any data from the table I just need to drop the FK and the table.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the table I tried to drop still exists in the database but I cannot access it

Comment: I would recommend that you ask on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a new database from scratch and pump data for every table except problematic one.

This error is not something that can be recovered by standard tools.

Restart Firebird server and make a copy of database file beforehand. It should leave you the file for a second attempt and normalize Firebird server internal structures that can be in inconsistent state after bugcheck.

Comment: Yeah its starting to look like that's going to be my only option